# Calling a living object from one Process while running in another Process

Tags: c#, .net, dll, out-of-process

Not really sure how to ask this question because I really don't know what I'm talking about. I have two DLLs (.NET), each is an AddIn that runs in two different application processes i.e. application one loads DLL one and application two loads DLL two. I wanted these DLLs to be able to communicate while loaded. In each DLL, I know the exact class that will be instantiated by the host process and I want these two living objects in each process to be able to communicate (call methods on each other). This seems like it would be possible. Has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some might say a dprecated technology [.Net Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28VS.71%29.aspx) is suited to this kind of inter-process object instance communications on the same host.

Comment: I looked (and I'm still looking) into .NET Remoting but I'm not sure yet if this is the solution I'm looking for. Thanks though

Comment: @enamrik If you need remote object instances to call methods on each other, remoting does this nicely. If you need to run more of a service, you can also look at WCF. They are both complicated technologies.

Comment: A combination of .NET Remoting and the singleton pattern did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to specify your requirements better please... there is .NET remoting to access and consume instances of objects running in another process/machine but should be used only when required.

in general WCF can be used to communicate between applications and processes but again it depends if you only want to call methods or also and absolutely have object level IPC.

Comment: Each DLL will have an object that will be created and alive the entire time the host application runs. The objects will be monitoring their host application and the objects will need to talk to each other about the changing states of their hosts. I looked (and I'm still looking) into .NET Remoting but I'm not sure yet if this is the solution I'm looking for.